# how to vectorize an array with variable column length

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have a numpy array a with int value and i would like to create an other array b with the same lenght and :

b[i]=np.prod(np.random.random(a[i]))

It's ok with a loop, but is it possible to vectorize otherwise my code is very slow (a is a very long array).

Thank's a lot if you have an idea.

Gonzague

Comment: It should be faster to generate all the required random values with one call, and use `reduceat` to take the product of blocks, something like: `np.multiply.reduceat( np.random.random(np.sum(a)+1), np.cumsum(a)) `.  The end points need tweaking.

Comment: very good idea thank's a lot